# How do I archive my tweets in Google Docs?

Tags: twitter, google-apps-script, google-docs-api

There are examples of Google App Scripts using Twitter's stream to search contents. What I am trying to achieve is to pull all my previous tweets and store it on a Google Spreadsheet. Is there a sample script that does that?

The closest I can find is http://mashe.hawksey.info/2012/01/twitter-archive-tagsv3/ but again it only performs search.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [If This Then That](https://ifttt.com) very easily, in fact you don't even have to spend the 5 minutes I just did and just use my recipe: https://ifttt.com/recipes/57275

:)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually I am using ifttt and I have blogged about ifttt at http://goo.gl/vtA0V

It does not work because I cannot choose which calendar. 

Also, I am looking for a programmatic solution. I appreciate your sharing though

Comment: Hmm, I set it up with a spreadsheet which is great for just storing the data, you should clarify the question that you want to put it in a calendar! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to write a little code, there is a really good [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/twitter_tutorial) on how to integrate with Twitter. The use case here is a bit different (around approving tweets), but there is another decent [snippet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_urlfetchapp#fetch) (see 2nd example) on code on how to populate a spreadsheet from a Twitter response.

When you mix and match the two pieces I think you can write this Twitter archiver.

I gave it a quick shot and it seemed to work pretty well. One thing to note is that the you may have to include some optional parameter for count and switch to the new Twitter API ([v1.1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline)) so you can go all the way back to your old Tweets.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Google Spreadsheet template in this post](http://mashe.hawksey.info/2012/12/backup-twitter-status-updates-v11/), which pulls a user timeline into a spreadsheet. It uses version 1.0 of the Twitter API so will break soon. You could just use this [other template](http://mashe.hawksey.info/2013/02/twitter-archive-tagsv5/) which is a search based solution which uses version 1.1 of the Twitter API and use the search operator from: e.g. from:mhawksey. If you just want to keep an archive of your tweets [this solution](http://mashe.hawksey.info/2013/01/sync-twitter-archive-with-google-drive/) uses Google Apps Script to keep a downloaded copy of your Twitter Archive fresh on Google Drive.